# Element ignores padding of container element

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML/CSS code:

```
<div id="container" style="padding:5px; width:600px;">  
    <div id="panel">
        <a style="padding:5px; color:#ffffff; background-color:#000000;">Page 1</a>

        <!-- Other anchor elements -->
    </div>

    <!-- Other panels -->
</div>
```

I struggle to understand why the `#panel` element sits comfortably within the `#container`; obeying the padding rules of it, whereas padding of the anchor element within the `#panel` overlaps the `#container`. Would anyone mind explaining why this is the case, and in doing so, perhaps suggest a fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think because its an inline element this occurs, if you change its display to `inline-block` the padding no longer overlaps. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/cajH6/)

Comment: Thanks, this does work, but do you know why inline elements behave the way I have described in the OP?

Comment: @TheBoss see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401140/padding-the-top-and-the-bottom-of-inline-element) question

Comment: Thank you. I do wish there were a good reason for this behaviour though, or if there is, a resource that explains why.

Comment: @TheBoss I searched w3c and found nothing.

Comment: I've tried also and found nothing... What a shame that we do not know why the W3C have chosen to implement inline elements in this way.