# li's height is larger than it's container in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a strange issue. Everything displays fine in both Chrome and IE, but not FireFox. See below:

[image]

The code for the navigation seen above is as follows

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/products/">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And the CSS

```
nav {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;

    text-align: center;
    background: #0054a6;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px -4px 10px 0;
}

nav li a {
    padding: 12px 75px;

    text-decoration: none;
    background: #0054a6;
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav li a:hover {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Why is the container not the same height as it's contents? I'm not looking for a fix, just an explanation as to why it does this with my code.

Comment: Try `nav li { padding: 0; }`

Comment: Try changing padding: 12px 75px to padding: 10px 75px in the nav li a selector? Padding adds to the height of the element, so the height of the anchor is actually bigger than the li

Comment: First thing I'd try is adding `display: block;` to your `a` elements. I'd also suggest wrapping your `li`s in an appropriate container (I'm guessing `ul`) so your markup is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing the effects of top and bottom padding on an inline element, your anchors. [See this previous answer for some background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401140/padding-the-top-and-the-bottom-of-inline-element). I've also made a [little fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/rA2sX/1/) which boils down your problem to something fairly obvious, I hope. (Basically, if the vertical padding exceeds the line-height on an inline element, the element can extend beyond the bounds of the container.)

So, your anchor elements are breaking out of their container, because they're inline, but with top and bottom padding set. To fix this (and as a bonus make their entire container clickable, rather than just the text) I'd turn them into blocks:

```
nav li a {
    display: block; /* Fix breakout problem */
    padding: 12px 75px;

    text-decoration: none;
    background: #0054a6;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

You should also wrap your `li` elements in a `ul`; they're not allowed to be children of the `nav` element.

(I'd probably consider getting rid of that wrapping `div`, too, and just targeting the `nav` element for your styling. I'm not sure it's adding anything. [This JSFiddle is my final adjustment to your code](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/X3fLc/2/).)

Comment: D'oh! Well, that's embarrassing. I fixed the code above, now the issue makes sense. But why doesn't it happen in Chrome or IE?

Comment: Interesting question. I can't try it in IE, but if I put your code [as-is into JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZ77s/) it shows the problem in  Chrome for me. Is there maybe some other styling going on? (Either in another stylesheet of yours, or perhaps in the brewers' default stylesheets?) Anyway, as long as it's working now...

Comment: Well I'm using a CSS reset, so maybe there is something happening there. I'll have to look further into the issue. Thanks for your help.