# div not covering its content height

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to do a sort of nav bar without using any pre existing library.

The problem is that I want the nav links to have a padding but the header is not covering their height.

Here's what I've done so far

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  color: #fefbed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding-right: 4.7%;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #115695;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

li {
  font-family: Montserratextrabold;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

li a {
  padding: 5%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  color: #fefbed;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index2.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="film.html">IL FILM</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a class="selected" href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The result is this one. Why?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Padding the top and the bottom of inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401140/padding-the-top-and-the-bottom-of-inline-element)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `a` tags are `inline` elements. Inline elements treat `margin` and `padding` differently than `block` elements. You can add `left` and `right` properties, but not `top` or `bottom`.

You can change the display to `inline-block` which will respect the `top` and `bottom` padding you set.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  color: #fefbed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding-right: 4.7%;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #115695;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

li {
  font-family: Montserratextrabold;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

li a {
  padding: 5%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  color: #fefbed;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index2.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="film.html">IL FILM</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a class="selected" href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I did mark this as a duplicate, but wanted to give an answer, because OP asked why the header wasn't expanding - and the duplicated doesn't answer the question explicitly.